# Регулярное выражение разбиение вхождения на 2 части

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Имеется выражение, работает нормально, но теперь надо результат разбить на 2 части, в голову ничего не приходит, разделять их надо через `/`. Что бы я только не пытался придумать, никак не получилось разбить сие на 2 части.

```
^.*(?=\s\[(\d{1,})\s.*\s(\d{1,})\])
```

Строки имеют такой вид:

```
Русское название / Oiginal name [04 из 12]
```

Comment: Не написали на каком языке,но на js,раз уже есть готовое выражение,я бы разбил просто через split(' / ')

Comment: @Александр: А регулярка с таким не справится? Дабы не делать лишних движений.

Comment: А изначально данные какие?Написал первое,что пришло в голову.

Comment: @Александр: строка, в которой через слеш написаны разные названия, и в скобках указано кол-во, извлечь названия, не разделив и получить кол-во легко, но думаю есть способ разбить на 2 группы названия.

Comment: Вы хотите сразу разбить строку Русское название / Oiginal name [04 из 12] на два массива,в первом [Русское название...] ,а во втором Oiginal name?

Comment: @Александр: Дада, именно так =)

Comment: .?(?!(\d)+ из (\d)+),а потом уже разбить через /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[\W]+(?=\s[/])|[a-zA-z]+\s?[a-zA-z]+
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вооот, спасибо! Дальше доделаю сам ^^

Comment: Переделал вашу регулярку, не со всеми вариантами текста справлялась,  полная версия: `[\W]+(?=\s[\/])|(?!\s)[\w\s]+(?=\s\[?\W?\d+?\s?\W+\d+\]?$)`

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего сделать через `String.Split`

```
var parts = str.Split('/');
var firstPart = parts[0];
var secondPart = parts[1];
```

Comment: В первом комментарии я уже предлагал

Comment: @Александр да, вижу, я не читал комментарии, сразу ответ написал.